# PHP echoing <img>/<a> with attributes

Tags: php, html

I need some help with echoing a `<img>` tag with attributes like title, rel, and class.

I have made it this far, when I'm echoing a filename from a db to search in a catalogue to find it. But I'm not sure how to write some attributes to it since I'm going to display it with Pirobox.

This is what i got working:

```
echo '<a href="uploads/'.$row['bildnamn'].'">';
echo '<img src="uploads/'.$row['thumb_bildnamn'].'">';
echo '</a>';
```

But I also need these attributes for the `<A>` tag which makes the image large.

```
rel="gallery"  class="pirobox_gall" title="$row['uploaded']" . " " . "$row['user']";
```

What I don't get to work is how to get that line together with:

```
echo '<a href="uploads/'.$row['bildnamn'].'">';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to concatenate everything in the `<a>` tag like so:

```
echo '<a href="uploads/' . $row['bildnamn'] . '" rel="gallery" class="pirobox_gall" title="' . $row['uploaded'] . ' ' . $row['user'] . '">';
echo '<img src="uploads/' . $row['thumb_bildnamn'] . '">';
echo '</a>';
```

I inserted spaces to help emphasize where PHP does concatenation. In your case, a single quote starts/ends the string for PHP; a double quote is ignored and goes into the HTML. So this part:

```
title="' . $row['uploaded'] . ' ' . $row['user'] . '"
```

will make the title be the value of the `uploaded` column, then a space, then the value of the `user` column. Then just end the `a` tag with a `>`.

Answer (score 0):

you could continue to concatenate the string

```
echo '<a href="uploads/'.$row['bildnamn'].'"'. 'rel="gallery"  class="pirobox_gall" title="'.$row['uploaded'].' '.$row['user'].'">';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo '<a href="uploads/' . $row['bildnamn'] . '" rel="gallery"  class="pirobox_gall" title="' . $row['uploaded'] . ' ' . $row['user'] . '">';
echo '<img src="uploads/' . $row['thumb_bildnamn'] . '">';
echo '</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using string concatenation, like this:

```
$anchor = '<a href="uploads/'.$row['bildnamn'].'"';
$anchor .= 'rel="gallery"  class="pirobox_gall" title="' . $row['uploaded'] . ' ' . $row['user'] . '">';
$anchor .= '<img src="uploads/'.$row['thumb_bildnamn'].'"></a>';
echo $anchor;
```